# Protect Question privilege lost after recalc and not regained

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, privileges, lost-reputation

Some weeks ago I passed the 15k rep mark on StackOverflow and earned the privilege to protect questions.

With the recent rep recalc I fell below the 15k mark and understandably lost the protection privilege. I have since climbed back and remained over 15k rep for a couple of days now and the protection privilege has not returned.

Is this a bug or has something else changed that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Have you actually tried to protect a question, or did you just not get the notification?

Comment: @Jon: In the brief period that I had the privilege I never actually found a question that would merit protection. But the link to protect was there next to the other privileges, something like: `link | edit | close | flag | protect` ... I also vaguely recollect clicking on the link and being confronted with a confirmation dialog. But that memory is hazy.

Comment: Yeah, so you're not seeing the link at all now?

Comment: That's right. I'm pretty sure it's an edge-case bug related to the recalc. There are probably very few users oscillated around 15k at that particular time and may not even know that they're missing a privilege.

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried recalculating your rep again? I don't deny this is a bug, but maybe we can find a way to fix it automatically.

Comment: How many percent do you see for protection at this page? http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: @S.Mark: Good call. I show the following: `protect questions 100%`

Comment: How do you recalc rep? I forgot where the link was. I know it's a bit obfuscated.

Comment: could you take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/131498) question and check protect button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation for recalc button.

Comment: btw, if you see your total reps is lower than 15k at /reputation, better not trigger recalc and should file report that "protect question privileges should  respect current reps instead of recalc'd reps'

Comment: wow. Just recalculated and landed at 14,998 rep!?! Thanks guys. Though this is really annoying. Two steps forward, one step back...

Comment: @S.Mark: I'm not too familiar with meta lingo. How does one file a report? Is it just a tag on a posted question? A sample link would be appreciated. Many thanks for yours and Jon's help btw.

Comment: you may check again for protect function, and don't say anyone else that I upvoted one of your post. :D

Comment: @Paul, don't believe my lingo too, I am just using a question as report when it is related to bug.

Comment: Thx! Still no protect privilege but I think that's a calculation that only happens a few times a day. Like the badges.

Comment: @Paul, I am not sure stackoverflow cache those now, but previously not like that, reps and privileges sync real-time before.

Comment: Are you still having any issues here?  This should have been resolved pretty quickly.

Comment: @NickCraver: I'm honestly not sure. I haven't noticed a recalc recently. I'm also 10k+ in rep past the protect privilege cutoff so if there are any boundary issues I would probably not be affected by them. (And I do see the protect link on the SO pages I open.)

Comment: @Paul - understood, marking this as status completed, it looks like it's been long-since fixed.